# Bash - grep to extract words ending with specified string; leave blank spaces where no match found

Tags: regex, bash, algorithm, text, grep

Here's the input data:

> I/o live/o in/o New/B-geo-loc York/I-geo-loc
>   I/o live/o somewhere/o in/o space/o
>   I/o would/o love/o to/o live/o in France/B-geo-loc
>   This/o is/o my/o home/o
>   Sanfrancisco/B-geo-loc CA/I-geo-loc is/o a/o great/o place/o to/o live/o

The aim is to extract all the words that end with "`/B-geo-loc`" or "`/I-geo-loc`" and also leave a blank line where no match is found

Tried using the following regular expression in grep, but didn't get the desired output

```
grep -o '\w*/B-geo-loc\b \w*/I-geo-loc\b' sourcefile.txt > targetfile.txt
```

This is my regex output:

> New/B-geo-loc York/I-geo-loc
>   Sanfrancisco/B-geo-loc CA/I-geo-loc

Instead of this desired ouput:

> New/B-geo-loc York/I-geo-loc
>   ---blank line---
>   France/B-geo-loc
>   ---blank line---
>   Sanfrancisco/B-geo-loc CA/I-geo-loc

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, it's not guaranteed by POSIX that `\w` or `\b` will be supported by grep, as neither of these is specified in BRE *or* ERE; it's thus safer from a portability perspective not to rely on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{c=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /\/[BI]-geo-loc$/) printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), $i; print ""}' file
New/B-geo-loc York/I-geo-loc

France/B-geo-loc

Sanfrancisco/B-geo-loc CA/I-geo-loc
```

Comment: Your answer inspired me to modify mine to kill the trailing whitespace -- there's no shame in being behind an awk-based answer on performance, but I'd rather not be second to anyone on correctness. :)

Comment: @Ed Morton I get the following error  when I run the awk script _awk: 1: unexpected character '.'_ Thanks

Comment: @Seanclick then you are not executing the script I posted and without seeing what you are running I can't help you diagnose that error message. Make sure you copy/paste the script, don't try to re-type it.

Comment: @Ed Morton this is awsome! worked perfectly...apparently I there was a slight typo in executing the script...copy/paste worked just fine..Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's no real obligation to use `grep` here, if it doesn't do what you want. The below is implemented in native bash (not POSIX sh -- use a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, not a `#!/bin/sh` one if embedding it in a script):

```
while read -r -a words; do
  matches=( )
  for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    [[ $word = */[IB]-geo-loc ]] && matches+=( "$word" )
  done
  printf '%s\n' "${matches[*]}"
done <sourcefile.txt >targetfile.txt
```

With a huge input file it might be worth rewriting to use ksh93 or awk, either of which has better performance than bash, but if you aren't spending measurable amounts of human time sitting around waiting for this to run it hardly matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
I/o live/o in/o New/B-geo-loc York/I-geo-loc
I/o live/o somewhere/o in/o space/o
I/o would/o love/o to/o live/o in France/B-geo-loc
This/o is/o my/o home/o
Sanfrancisco/B-geo-loc CA/I-geo-loc is/o a/o great/o place/o to/o live/o

$ perl -lne 'print join " ", m#\w+/B-geo-loc|\w+/I-geo-loc#g' ip.txt
New/B-geo-loc York/I-geo-loc

France/B-geo-loc

Sanfrancisco/B-geo-loc CA/I-geo-loc
```

- `m#\w+/B-geo-loc|\w+/I-geo-loc#g` gives all the matches, `m` allows using another character than `/` as delimiter

  - Can also use `m#\w+/(?:B-geo-loc|I-geo-loc)#g` or `m#\w+/[IB]-geo-loc#g`
- `print join " ",` use space as separator for printing the matches